# Problemas no implode ao trazer resultados do banco de dados

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela onde armazeno as permissões de acesso a um sistema. Ele está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo bem, porém ao listar as permissões de cada usuário ( só tem 02 usuários cadastrados ) na visualização dos administradores, está trazendo duplicidade de dados. O código que estou usando é:

```
while($jmVisualizar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlAdm)){

    $sqlPermissao = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM permissao_adm 
    WHERE IDAdministrador = '".$jmVisualizar->IdAdmin."';"); 

    $jmPermissao = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlPermissao);

    if($jmPermissao->Cadastrar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Cadastrar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Visualizar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Visualizar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Editar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Editar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Excluir == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Excluir";
    }

    // Testar
    echo implode(",", $visualiza)."<br>";
}
```

Ele  está me retornando:

```
Cadastrar,Visualizar,Editar,Excluir
Cadastrar,Visualizar,Editar,Excluir,Visualizar,Editar
```

Quando na verdade é pra me retornar:

```
Cadastrar,Visualizar,Editar,Excluir
Visualizar,Editar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa *resetar* a *array* `$visualiza` a cada `while` para atingir este objetivo.

Crie um `$visualiza = array()` dentro do `while`, assim a cada vez irá *resetar* os valores anteriormente obtido.

```
while($jmVisualizar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlAdm)){

    // Cria uma nova array:
    $visualiza = [];

    $sqlPermissao = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM permissao_adm 
    WHERE IDAdministrador = '".$jmVisualizar->IdAdmin."';"); 

    $jmPermissao = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlPermissao);

    if($jmPermissao->Cadastrar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Cadastrar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Visualizar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Visualizar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Editar == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Editar";
    }if($jmPermissao->Excluir == '1'){
        $visualiza[] = "Excluir";
    }

    // Testar
    echo implode(",", $visualiza)."<br>";
}
```

---

Comment: Obrigado Inkeliz, funcionou!